# Can I "export" a Restore point on an external HDD?

Tags: windows, system-restore

I would like to know if (in Win XP, 7 & 8) you can "export" a restore point to an external HDD? Why can't I choose a path to where I would like to have the RP created?

Answer (score 0):

Probably this command can help you!

```
recimg -CreateImage d:\RefreshImage
```

This link should help you to know about recimg

[recimg](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_rt-system/recimg-on-windows-rt/e3bdf55b-58cb-4148-84c1-9dd488076046)